# JS, how to launch app on a specific monitor?

Tags: javascript, display, monitor

i chose and read a PPT file from an html page on a Windows 10 computer with dual monitors, this is the code:

```
<script>
    function read() {
        var x = document.getElementById("input").files[0].name;
        window.location = x;
    }
```

Is there a way to force the display of the ppt reader always on the same monitor. I know that if you close the window in a monitor, it will reopen on the same, but i looking for a more reliable solution. Thanks for your informations

Answer (score 0):

**Opening an app in a particular window** is a feature of the operating system. It cannot be controlled in browser.

In a multi-screen setup, Windows 10 remembers the monitor on which a specific application (Example: Powerpoint) was opened recently, and tries to open the next file in the same monitor again.

Therefore, if there are 2 monitors, and if any powerpoint file is manually moved to monitor # 2 once, then Windows will continue to use monitor #2 for all PPT files opened subsequently.

**More information:**
https://windowsreport.com/move-apps-between-monitors-windows-10/